# Conditional style rendering with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component which render elements. The width of each element depends on `minimized` value (`true` or `false`). I need conditional style binding without class here.

I tried:

`{ conversation.minimized == false ? right: $index * 285 + 'px' : right: $index * 150 + 'px' }`

but it didn't work and i got errors.

Comment: Should be `v-bind:style="{ right: conversation.minimized ? $index * 150 + 'px' : $index * 285 + 'px' }"`

Comment: I did it different way.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really get your code but if you want conditional style binding you can do like that:

```
<template>
    <div
        :style="condition ? { 'color': 'red' } : { 'color': 'blue' }"
    >
        Some data
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            condition: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. but you want to make a div smaller or bigger? If so, you can use a computed var to evaluate that value. And because it's reactive, if you change any of those values it will evaluate the value on the fly.

a small example:

```
<style>
  .classA {float:right,width:200px}
  .classB {float:right,width:400px}
</style>
```

on your HTML

```
<div id="#app">
<div class="{{ classChanger }}">your stuff</div>
</div>
```

and on your Vue

```
computed:{
    classChanger: function(){
        var theClass = 'classB';
        if(this.conversation.minimized == false){
            theClass = 'classA';
        }
        return theClass:
    }
}
```

It harder without knowing your code exactly.

Comment: Exactly, I want to make div smaller or bigger depends of its minimized or not. Could you show me an example how that should look?

Comment: updated my answer with an example without knowing the code is more dificult

Comment: That wasn't what I actually needed. I posted my working code so you can check it out. Thanks for advice anyway!

Comment: Use `:class="classChanger"` and not `class="{{ classChanger }}"` to work with current Vue

Comment: You can simplify that computed into a one liner... `return !this.conversation.minimized ? 'classA' : 'classB';`

Answer (score 2):

```
currentItemPosition: function(index, conversation) {
            var indexOfCurrentElement = this.conversations.indexOf(conversation);  
            var right = 0;

            if (indexOfCurrentElement > 0) {
                for (var i=0; i<indexOfCurrentElement; i++) {
                    if (!this.conversations[i].minimized) {
                        right += 285;
                    } else {
                        right += 170;
                    }
                }
                return "right: " + right + "px";

            } else {
                return "right: 0px";
            } 
        }
    }
```

That's how i solved my problem.

`<div class="card" v-bind:style="currentItemPosition($index, conversation)">`

Works perfectly for me right now. There was to much logic anyway to do it in line with `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

To make things more modular, we could create a component that would wrap the logic for the div and the styles. The usage would be:

```
<card :index="$index" :minimized="conversation.minimized"></card>
```

And the definition of the component is:

```
Vue.component( 'card', {
    props: ['index', 'minimized'],
    template: '\
        <div class="card" :style=[cardStyles]>\
    ',
    computed: function () {
        cardStyles: function () {
            var ratio = this.minimized ? 150 : 285;
            return {
                right: ( this.index * ratio ) + 'px'
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

It receives the `index` and the `minified` value, and then uses a computed function to obtain the div styles.